# Count how many times a value appears continuously in Hive/SQL

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I've got 3 columns in my table. And I'd like to count, for each userid, ordered by time, how many times the `value` equals `B` continuously. Something like the longest sublist with the same value. For example, data below

`time    userid  value
2016-01-01  1   A
2016-01-02  1   B
2016-01-03  1   B
2016-01-04  2   C
2016-01-05  2   B
2016-01-06  2   B
2016-01-07  2   B
2016-01-08  2   C
2016-01-09  2   B`

would return

`userid times
1 2
2 3`

Is this even possible without user defined function in Hive? I've digged a bit into `LAG` or `LEAD`, but couldn't find a way. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      value
           ,userid               
           ,max (times) as times


from       (select      value
                       ,userid
                       ,count (*)   as times

            from       (select  value
                               ,userid

                               ,row_number () over 
                                (
                                     partition by userid       
                                     order by     time
                                ) as rn

                               ,row_number () over 
                                (
                                    partition by userid,value 
                                    order by     time
                                ) as rn_val

                        from    t

                     -- where   value = 'B'
                        ) t

            group by    value
                       ,userid  
                       ,rn - rn_val 
            ) t

group by    value
           ,userid  

order by    value
           ,userid 
;
```